# Unexpected behavior when copying iterators using tee

Tags: python, loops, iterator

If you copy an iterator inside a for loop, the iteration resumes just fine. For example:

```
ita = iter(range(5))
for a in ita:
    print(a)
    if a == 2:
        ita, itb = tee(ita)
```

prints `0 1 2 3 4`. However, if you iterate over the second copy made, the original iterator depletes as well:

```
ita = iter(range(5))
for a in ita:
    print(a)
    if a == 2:
        ita, itb = tee(ita)
        for b in itb:
            pass
```

only prints `0 1 2`.

As far as I understand it, iterating over the copied iterator shouldn't affect the original one, so I don't know why this is happening. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: (1) Although you set `ita` in the for-loop this doesn't affect the `ita` in the `for a in ita` because it was only evaluated once (to the initial iterator) when the loop was entered first. (2) The iterators returned by `tee` are independent from each other but `tee` has to read from its input iterator to fill its returned iterators when one of the returned iterators is read.

Comment: This can be an answer..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`tee` creates two iterators from one iterator. Each of those two created iterators can be used independently, i.e. consuming one of them does not consume th other one.

However, the original iterator has to be consumed. For example:

```
a = iter(range(5))
b, c = tee(a)
for value in b:
    pass
```

At this point, `b` is consumed. By consuming `b`, `a` has been consumed as well, but `c` has not been consumed. See:

```
>>> list(a)
[]
>>> list(b)
[]
>>> list(c)
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Now, in the original code, the same variable name is use for two things:

```
ita, itb = tee(ita)
```

There are 3 iterators here, but two of them are using variable name `ita`. That is the cause of the  confusion. The new `ita` iterator does not get consumed together with `itb`, but the old one does.

Note that the original `ita` is used in `for a in ita:`, and not the new one. That is because it `ita` variable was read only the first time the `for` line was executed and then assigning something else to `ita` does not affect the loop.

You can see that the new `ita` is not consumed by adding this one line:

```
ita = iter(range(5))
for a in ita:
    print(a)
    if a == 2:
        ita, itb = tee(ita)
        for b in itb:
            pass
        print(list(ita))  # dded line
```

Prints:

```
0
1
2
[3, 4]
```

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation for `tee` states](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.tee):

> Once `tee()` has made a split, the original *iterable* should not be used anywhere else; otherwise, the *iterable* could get advanced without the tee objects being informed.

The behavior you are triggering is the opposite of what is discussed in the docs (`tee` is advancing the iterator without informing the *other* consumer of `ita` [the `for` loop]), but it causes the exact same kind of problem.

To put it another way, `tee` assumes it owns the passed-in iterator (the pseudo-Python in the "for learning purposes" implementation shows as much) - and since the iterator for `iter` is stateful, when `tee` consumes the remaining elements in `ita` it empties out the remaining entries in `ita` before the next turn of your `for` loop.